# How to auto-scale image in React Native?

Tags: react-native

There is a picture with a fixed `aspectRatio`. How do I resize it to fit the container or calculate the height when `width: '100%'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just put the image into the container with width=100%, Please try
width=100% + resizeMode=contain

For example

```
<Image

  resizeMode={'contain'}
  style={{ flex:1, 
  width:'100%',
        aspectRatio: 1 }}
  source={{uri: "https://www.yoursite.com/images/" + item.photo}}
/>
```

or

```
import { Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

const image = () => (
    <View style={styles.imgContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require('assets/images/image.png')} />
    </View>
);

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    imgContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    image: {
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        flex: 1,
        aspectRatio: 1 // Your aspect ratio
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant I set an image witdh to 100%, in order to fit the container

Comment: I see, I have posted the 2nd method, please see whether it fits your need.